# Pandas.DataFrame select by interval of indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know, in a pythonic way, how could I select elements in the Pandas.Dataframe inside a given interval in their indexes. Basically I wish to know if there is a command like pandas.Series.between for DataFrame.index .

example:

> df1 = pd.DataFrame(x, index=(1,2,...,100000000), columns=['A','B','C'])
>
> df2 = df1.between(start=10, stop=100000)

I think it is curious not easily finding anything related to this.

Answer (score 8):

You can just use the subscript notation with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) which is label based indexing:

```
In [3]:

df2 = df1.loc[10:100000]
df2
Out[3]:
         A    B    C
10     NaN  NaN  NaN
11     NaN  NaN  NaN
12     NaN  NaN  NaN
13     NaN  NaN  NaN
14     NaN  NaN  NaN
15     NaN  NaN  NaN
.....
99994  NaN  NaN  NaN
99995  NaN  NaN  NaN
99996  NaN  NaN  NaN
99997  NaN  NaN  NaN
99998  NaN  NaN  NaN
99999  NaN  NaN  NaN
10000  NaN  NaN  NaN

[99991 rows x 3 columns]
```

You also mention not being able to find documentation about this but it's pretty easy to find and clear: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: That (by which I mean `iloc`) actually won't work without a tweak for the OP's case, as the OP's index begins with 1.. could just use `loc`, though, no?

Comment: @DSM So you're suggesting something where the index value is 10 up to 10000 correct? will update

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear. I want to find values inside a interval, and not slice it with loc.

Comment: @Galdaran please explain `loc` selects labels that match those values as my output shpws, it is not simply selecting the 10th row up to 10000th row.

Comment: @EdChum OK, for example, if I do  'loc[10:100]' I receive a error point to the inexistence of the index=10, in case it does not exist in my DataFrame. What I wish is a scan inside a given interval. Like the Series.between command.

Comment: well `df[(df.index>=10) & (df.index<=100)]` will return what you want without an error